# How to find the time complexity of the below function?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

I am facing difficulty to figure out the time complexity of this below function. Please help to find how to solve this question?

```
    int sumOfDigits(int n){
    int sum;` 
    if(n < 10){
        return n;
    }
    sum = (n % 10) + sumOfDigits(n / 10);
    return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function considers each digit of a number `n` and returns the sum of them.

The number of iterations is `⌊log10(n)⌋ + 1` and depends on the number of digits of `n`. Therefore, `T(n) = O(log n)`